# Thymeleaf = how to th:each adding value in tag input

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

so I want to make input income/outcome increase according to the income/outcome data that has been obtained from the controller

I have tried using th:each as follows to add income/outcome from each transaction

this is my form

```
    <form class="form-horizontal" th:action="@{/report/create}" method="post">
        <div th:each="transactions : ${transaction}">
            <input type="hidden" name="income" th:value="${report.income + transactions.income}">
            <input type="hidden" name="outcome" th:value="${report.outcome + transaction.outcome}">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

with that I only got the first income/outcome from the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how you implemented the backend, but your spelling for transactions isn't correct. Other than that, it should work as I've done something similar myself in the past. Typically you would have

```
@GetMapping("/my-page")
public String showAll(Model model) {
    //....
    model.addAttribute("report", report);
    // however you define (a list) of transactions
    model.addAttribute("transactions", transactions);
    return "my-page";
}
```

then in your html

```
    <div th:each="transaction : ${transactions}">
        <input type="hidden" name="income" th:value="${report.income + transaction.income}">
        <input type="hidden" name="outcome" th:value="${report.outcome + transaction.outcome}">
```

Comment: omg, it works . thank you so much (n) , im just make a model for the report thats the problem.